# Conditional Select and Update rows with previous/next rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with a column 'id' which is autoincrement in SQLite. In some records I have zero values. I want to 1. Select and also 2.Update them.
Condition is as follows: if col1 (= t in next example) value is equal to next row, then update row by next row, else use previous row for updating. Here next means id + 1 and previous means id - 1.
How can I do that? (I need 2 queries: one for selecting based on above condition and another one for updating)

This query returns those records with zero values:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE col2 = 0
```

which returns:

```
id    t     col2  col3 .....  coln
15  19:48     0     0  .....    0
23  20:53     0     0  .....    0
```

Sample data:

```
id    t     col2  col3 .....  coln
14  19:47     5    6   .....    7
15  19:48     0    0   .....    0
16  19:49     10   11  .....    12
...
22  20:52     15   16  .....    17
23  20:53     0     0  .....    0
24  20:53     20   21  .....    22
```

Expected result:

```
id    t     col2  col3 .....  coln
15  19:48     5    6   .....    7
23  20:53     20   21  .....    22
```

Comment: Post sample data and expected results for that sample data to clarify, better in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27

Comment: Why is row with id=15 updated? t in row with id=14 or id=16 is not equal to t of that row.

Comment: row with id=15 is updated because it has zero values for col2,col3,.... Time (t field) in row=15 is not equal to time in row=16, so row=14 is used for filling these zero values. In row=23, time is equal to row=24, so row 24 is used for filling zeros in row=23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery that returns either the next row if it contains he same value of `t` or the previous row:

```
update tablename
set (col2, col3, ..., coln) = ( 
  select tab.col2, tab.col3, ..., tab.coln
  from tablename tab
  where (tab.id = tablename.id + 1 and tab.t = tablename.t) or (tab.id = tablename.id - 1)
  order by tab.id desc limit 1
)  
where (col2, col3, ..., coln) = (0, 0, ..., 0)
  and exists (
        select 1 from tablename tab 
        where  (tab.id = tablename.id + 1 and tab.t = tablename.t) or (tab.id = tablename.id - 1)
      )
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=17ec3b77166e0f6d84c8903f02038dd6).